# React on windows/tab close not showing dialog

Tags: reactjs, typescript, addeventlistener, dom-events

I am trying to display a dialog when the user closes the window (or tab) in React with typescript.

I read that we can't override the default dialog. That's ok, but for me even the default dialog do not appears.

If I debug the react app in Chrome, the message got shown when I go step by step. If not in debug , the message are not shown and the page got closed.
Tried so many examples on the internet, none worked for me.
This is my last try what works as described earlier.
Any idea?

```
interface IProsp{}
interface Istate{}

class ExtrasDesktop extends React.Component<IPros, IState>
{
    componentDidMount()
    {
        window.addEventListener('beforeunload', this.keepOnPage);
    }
    componentWillUnmount()
    {
        window.removeEventListener('beforeunload', this.keepOnPage);
    }

    keepOnPage = (e: BeforeUnloadEvent): any =>
    {
        e.preventDefault();
        const message = 'Some message';
        e.returnValue = message;
        return message;
    }

    render()
    {}
}
```

Comment: syntax looks correct, the problem is that in production mode it is not working?

Comment: Not working in any enviorment.

Comment: are you sure you have your component rendered in the DOM ?

Comment: Yes, as I wrote, I can debug it.